# How can I keep debug on when device is turned off?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, restart

Some testers warned me about an issue that will rise when my app is becoming active from background when the device is restarted. I can replicate the issue, but it's hard to debug because obviously Xcode looses connection to my device when it is turned off and don't reconnect automatically to it when it is turned on again.

To get the reconnection, I have to unplug the device from the USB cable, plug it again and build and run from Xcode. The problem is that this will cause the app to restart and the issue disappears.

How am I supposed to overcome this problem?

Comment: it is due to overheating problem . i guess ! any corelocation or background downloading is there in code !

Comment: do you want to see LOG of App? While its not connected to XCode?

Comment: try crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com for crash reports.